# Expression - Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Gu

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have written following lambda expression

```
Expression<Func<ContractObject, bool>> objExpression = 
i => i.ContractProjects.Any(a => ProjectList.Any(p => p.Id == a.ProjectId));
```

`ContractProjects` and `ProjectList` are List of two different types sharing common values ie. ProjectId and Id respectively.

But it is throwing following exception. Is there any changes that I have to do or can this expression be written in some another way?

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: Is this LINQ to objects or LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Those who have flagged this question as  unclear.. Please study LINQ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many trial and error I got the following solution as follows

```
List<Int32> projectIds = new List<Int32>();

foreach (Project p in ProjectList)
    projectIds.Add(p.Id);

Expression<Func<ContractObject, bool>> objExpression = 
i => i.ContractProjects.Any(a => projectIds.Contains(a.ProjectId)));
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Correct. The `List<Project>` (assuming typename `Project`) object cannot be translated to SQL since it is a complex type. Since you are only using the `ProjectId` value in the query, you have to translate the list to a list (or array) of simple (=value) types, since they **can** be translated to SQL (they are translated to SQL parameters).

Comment: You can simplify it: `var projectIds = ProjectList.Select(x => x.ProjectId).ToArray();`, or `.ToList();`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your ContractList might not have been created yet

try :

```
var objExpression = i => i.ContractProjects.ToList()
                          .Any(a => ProjectList.Any(p => p.Id == a.ProjectId));
```